# Json and printing the resulting array into variables

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am using cURL to get json information from a site that pulls a random tumblr picture from a list of sources and I am interested of putting the json data retrieved into php variables so I can call for example, just the image url

```
$url = "http://someurl.com";
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);

            $a = curl_exec($ch);
                    $json = var_dump(json_decode($a, true));
```

I get:

```
array(3) {
  'image' =>
  array(1) {
    [0] =>
    string(62) "http://picture.jpg"
  }
  'source' =>
  string(31) "http://source.tumblr.com"
  'page' =>
  string(9) "/page/164"
}
```

What would I now do in order to just print the url for the image?

I have tried

```
$url = $json["image"][0];
```

and then calling $url, but it gives me nothing in return. What I am doing wrong?

I have never worked with json before so I am at a loss here, any help is appreciated!

Comment: What happens if you just print out `$json['image']`?

Comment: try $json = json_decode($a, true); can you show full example you have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to code looks:-

try
change

```
$json = var_dump(json_decode($a, true));
```

to

```
$json = json_decode($a, true);
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked out just fine. If you don't mind, do explain why it works without var_dump. I am somewhat still of a newbie to php and I'd love to learn more.

Comment: @Chidorid if the answer is fine you first mark it accepted by clicking the tick on the left

Comment: you have seted your var_dump output in your $json var then how it will parse as array? got it or i need to describe more

Comment: @SaadChaudhry, There was apparently a 5 minute timer before I could mark it as answered, done now! =)
RakeshSharma, Appears I was at a loss on how var_dump works, was using it to print the structure of the array. Thanks for the answer!